# Install Ubuntu alongside windows, but use windows boot manager

Tags: system-installation, windows-10, bootloader, grub-efi

Is there a scenario, where I install Ubuntu without Grub and am able to run it manually.(I know Grub is responsible for booting, but I have to ask anyway, may be there is a way).

I ask this because, in the past, when I'd decided to remove Ubuntu (and delete its partition), I had to fix win boot manager. For some reason, when I go to step 'bootrec /fixmrb' I get 'access denied'. And I could never resolve this, many times I've had to make clean install on windows.
Is this doable ?

Comment: No, the Windows bootloader only boots Windows. How long ago was that situation when you had to fix boot after removing Ubuntu?. It happened ~10 yeras ago with BIOS, it doesn't happen with UEFI mode, "mandatory" for any preinstalled Windows 8 or newer since 2012! And even with BIOS there were never the need to reinstall Windows, its bootloader can always be reinstalled from the WinPE environment with installation media. Previous questions also suggest you need a serious update.

Comment: Okay ,  thanks for this.

Answer (score -1):

If you install `Grub2Win` in *Windows* you can choose not to install `Grub` (when you install *Ubuntu*). It would not be my choice though.

Comment: Okay, I'll check about this.

Comment: @VeritLibert Unless you want problems don't check it.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Not having problems at all with Grub2Win. Had set it as my default bootloader to see if I run into any problems. And I didn't have any. Can boot Win10, Mint Una, Kubuntu 20.04.5, as well as Peppermint.iso and Xubuntu.iso.